# Как часы/минуты/секунды в таймере разделить на 2 части?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть таймер:

```
function update() {
    var Now = new Date(), Finish = new Date();
    Finish.setHours( 23);
    Finish.setMinutes( 59);
    Finish.setSeconds( 59);
    if( Now.getHours() === 23  &&  Now.getMinutes() === 59  &&  Now.getSeconds === 59) {
        Finish.setDate( Finish.getDate() + 1);
    }
    var sec = Math.floor( ( Finish.getTime() - Now.getTime()) / 1000);
    var hrs = Math.floor( sec / 3600);
    sec -= hrs * 3600;
    var min = Math.floor( sec / 60);
    sec -= min * 60;
    $(".timer .hours").text( pad(hrs));
    $(".timer .minutes").text( pad(min));
    $(".timer .seconds").text( pad(sec));
    setTimeout( update, 200);
}
function pad(s) { return ('00'+s).substr(-2) }
update();
```

Сейчас часы, минуты и секунды выводятся в соответствующий блок.
Как разделить часы/минуты/секунды на 2 части, чтобы выводить в следующем вормате:

```
<div class="timer">
    <div class="hours">
        <span>0</span>
        <span>5</span>
    </div>
    <div class="minutes">
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="seconds">
        <span>2</span>
        <span>2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function pad(s) {
  //преобразуем в строку с 2мя цифрами
  s=('00'+s).substr(-2);
  //отправляем каждую цифру в соответствующий блок
  return '<span>' + s[0] + '<span></span>' + s[1] + '</span>';

}

console.log(pad(2))
console.log(pad(23))
```

Соответственно вместо

```
$(".timer .hours").text( pad(hrs));
```

используем

```
$(".timer .hours").html( pad(hrs));
```